# c++ public vs private inheritancce

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I don't understand and i really don't get public vs private inheritance in classes.
Suppose we have the following code:

```
class A {
    int A_a;
protected:
    int A_b;
public:
    int A_c;
};
class B : public A {
    int B_a;
protected:
    int B_b;
public:
    int B_c;
};

class C : private A {
    int C_a;
protected:
    int C_b;
public:
    int C_c;
};
```

I know it has to be with access rights over vars and funcs, but doing all the tests i really can grasp it and i don't know when to apply public or private inheritance;

Comment: This is not a site for explaining the basic semantics of  a programming language - that's what textbooks are for. Which C++ textbook are you using?

Comment: Sorry, i know. But my english in sometimes missleading and im using this old book in pdf "Object-Oriented Programming in C++,
Fourth Edition".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is simple sheme (base class -> derived clas) how visibility of class members change with different types of inheritance:

Public inheritance:

- public -> public
- protected -> protected
- private -> private

Protected inheritance:

- public -> protected
- protected -> protected
- private -> private

Private inheritance:

- public -> private
- protected -> private
- private -> private

Here you have few simple examples https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_inheritance.htm